# Riemann Stieltjes integration

Tags: integration, analysis, stieltjes-integral

Given $f(x)=k $ where k is a constant and $g(x)=x^2 \in [a,b]$, how do I find the the Riemann Stieltjes integrals, $\int fdg$ and $\int gdf$ taken over the intervals [a,b]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition is
$$
\int k d\left(x^2\right) = \int k (2x)dx = kx^2+C
$$
and similarly can you compute the other one? Should be very easy.